# Change url structure for all files in a folder using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla, url-rewriting

Since we updated from Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3.2 URL's have changed from:

Example: 
http://domain.com/blog/name-of-post.html 
to 
http://domain.com/blog-name/entry/name-of-post

My question is how do I redirect all blog posts to have the new url structure? What's the best way so I don't have to go one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/blog/(.+)\.html$ /blog-name/entry/$1
```

in the htaccess file in your document root.